# Nativescript - getting strange behavior in formattedString and Span

Tags: nativescript

On setting certain foregroundColor, I'm gettting a inner shadow on the text - no other attributes are set.

```
span = new spanModule.Span();
span.foregroundColor = new colorModule.Color("green");
span.text = "test";
formattedString.spans.push(span);
```

Funny thing is that it happens with certain colors only.

So far, cyan, blue and green.

This is on Android - not tested on iOS.

In the image both "10" and "D" are part of the same formattedString but different spans - the difference is the foregroundColor and in the "D" the fontSize has been set. Actually if I change the color of the "D" to cyan also - there's a shadow. Even if I take out the fontSize.

[image]

Comment: Please add some example screenshot, to illustrate the problem

Comment: Some further info. The formattedString is assigned to a Label which is inside a StackLayout. If I set the background of the layout to red - I get this shadowed font on the text. If I remove the background color, then no shadow. Seems like a bug in {N}.